# how performance differs in loop declarations

Tags: javascript

how these two for loops differs in performance and why? what is the best way to iterate

```js
var letters=
    ['a','b','c','d','e','f','','','',''];
   var start=new Date()
   for(var i=0,abc=letters.length;i<abc;i++){
    alert(letters[i]);
   }
   var end=new Date()
   alert(end-start)
   var letters1=['a','b','c','d','e','f','','','',''];
   var start1=new Date()
   for(var i=0;i<letters1.length;i++){
    alert(letters1[i]);
   }
   var end1=new Date()
   alert(end1-start1);
```

Comment: These things don't differ in performance your benchmark is wrong. Benchmarking with a blocking IO op like `alert` is very bad.

Comment: well testing this with alerts is obsolet because the loop will stop as long as you did not click ok

Comment: JS interpreters optimize your code and one form usually ends up getting transformed into another. In practice it doesn't matter.

Comment: thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum john Smith.... I just started learning javascript....

Comment: Benchmarking is actually quite a challenging thing. Don't be tempted to believe benchmarks so quickly, do read about micro benchmarks and their perils.

Comment: Mahesh, check out http://jsperf.com

Comment: You can compare different loops using jsperf. For example: http://jsperf.com/fastest-array-loops-in-javascript/56. Your variants are "for loop basic" and "for loop cached".

BTW, "for loop basic" is the fastest on my Chrome, outperforming "for loop cached" by a lot.

Comment: @Qwerty that benchmark is also pretty bad, just for the record.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, OK. It was just the first in the list https://www.google.com/webhp#q=jsperf+for+loop+length :) You could write your better version and make it popular.

Comment: @Qwerty for loops usually spend a tiny amount in the actual loop construct and most of the time executing the payload - these benchmarks are mostly worthless anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that particular test is calling a function that does simple math operations. What do you suggest as a payload?

Comment: @Qwerty something that doesn't de-populate the shared mutable array though `shift` destroying it and then make all the following tests run a no-op would be a nice start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In old browsers, caching the limit of a loop when iterating over objects like arrays was nearly always much faster than getting the limit (e.g. *array.length*) every time. In modern browsers, not so much.

Caching usually only has a significant performance benefit if the object being iterated is a type that the script engine knows might change during iteration, but doesn't.

For example, if iterating over a [*live NodeList*](http://jsperf.com/cached-for-dynamic-object):

```
var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i=0, iLen=nodeList.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  // do stuff
}
```

is measurably (if not noticeably) faster in browsers than:

```
for (var i=0; i<nodeList.length; i++) {
  // do stuff
}
```

However, as others have noted, the work done in the loop may be far more significant so that saving a few cycles in the test is not useful. But for some, their standard loop pattern includes caching the limit if it isn't modified in the loop and do it always.

BTW, for measuring time in a browsers there is the [High Resolution Time specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/) (also see [MDN *Peformance.now*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now)).

Answer (score 2):

as i mentioned in comment testing with alerts is absolute nonsense because it pauses the loop

you can compare js performance for example on http://jsperf.com/

heres the result: 
UPDATE: made some better testing

[image]

snippet 1 seems to be better becau it caches the result of letters.length
heres the test: http://jsperf.com/testing-perf-fo-for-loop

Comment: What is the URL of the test?

Comment: Using console.log is probably a blocking operation, bad for compare.

Comment: Your tests is equally bad. Please consider learning more about benchmarks and the perils of jsperf

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Is there a good writeup about the "perils of jsperf"?

Comment: @kol If you're testing Chrome - anything by people who worked on v8. In particular, I'm a fan of this guy: http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html

Comment: @kol it's also worth mentioning that a lot of things that it didn't do in 2012 like dead code elimination - v8 happily does today.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum ... which for loop syntax declaration is good and why? any other cases where these loops might differ?

Comment: @MaheshG focus on learning the language and the constructs, use the constructs and formulate an opinion. Readability and maintainability is more meaningful than performance in 97% of cases anyway - especially if you're learning a new language. I'd personally use `letters.forEach` because it's the most readable and simplest IMO - but if it's between the two I'd use the one that doesn't do `abc=letters.length` because it's less things to type.